# NULL values, regression / correlation switch

Tags: r, null, correlation

I have a dataset with lets say 2 variables. I want to do some regression testing, but the quite a few numeric observations have "NULL". I would want to use this as a value however, but I don't want to convert it to a specific number, ie 99999.

I keep trying all the different ways after googling and it doesn't work.

```
Benny2 <- read_excel("C:/Users/EH9508/Desktop/Benny2.xlsx")
```

I have two variables `"Days"` and `"Amount"`  both have numeric values and "NULL"

Any help would be appreicated.

Comment: what library are you referring to xlsx? openxlsx? Have you tried to specify the right SHEET?

Comment: library(openxlsx), only 1 sheet, the data is being read in, but I want character "NULL" to be used as a number even though it isn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the file/sheet to csv from Excel (save as > csv) and then:

```
mydata <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

If you don't have access to Excel, then this is how it goes with the xlsx library:

```
library("xlsx")
mydata <- read.xlsx("path/to/file.xlsx")
```

If you put the csv/xlsx file in the same folder as your R script, you can type the file name without the path as `read.xlsx("file.xlsx")`.

If you already have your data in R and are wondering how to get the NULL converted to a given value, try this:

```
mydata <- matrix(rnorm(10),5,2)  # You data
mydata[2,1] <- NA  # Some NA
mydata[5,2] <- NA

mydata[is.na(mydata)] <- 99999  # Replaces mydata where NA for 99999
```